# How many bit strings are there containing # 0's, and # 1's... Counting Problem Help?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling on these 2 problems:

- How many 16 bit strings are there containing six 0's and ten 1's
  with no consecutive 0's?
- How many 8 bit strings with exactly 2 1's are there such that the 1's
  are not adjacent?

For the first one, I am guessing they must alternate between 0 and 1 but I have no clue how to set this up. How can I use combinations to find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't space out; select the spaces!   Put `0`,`0`,`0`,`0`,`0`, and `0` into `_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_1_`

You have ten `1` and eleven spaces to place the six `0` such that only one `0` goes in any space.  How many ways can you select six of these eleven spaces?

Second verse, same as the first.  (Only the numbers are changed.)

Comment: So, for the first one it is  C(16,10) * C(16,6) ? Is that correct?

Comment: No ... What are you even counting there?  The count of ways to select 6 of 11 items is $^{11}\mathrm C_6$

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite think it through. So would have been C(11,6) * C(16,10) I am guessing.

Comment: @user3015986 Stop guessing. *Think* about what you are counting.  You are given 10 ones and 6 zeroes.  You don't need to select them! You have them.  You just need to count ways to *arrange* them.  So we place the ones down in a row.  There's just one way to do that; they're all ones.  Then we take the zeroes and place them in the *spaces* before, after, or between the ones so that there's at most 1 zero in each space.  There are 11 such spaces and 6 zeros.  So we *only* need to count the ways to select 6 of the 11 spaces.  Just that.

Comment: I had the similar idea which my book showed, but I think I got it mixed up with something else or didn't understood the question completely. But thanks so much for your help. Now I get it.